# How to pass data of all input fields from one page to another using button in python django

Tags: python, django, web, django-views, django-templates

I have a form on index.html and I want to pass data of all input fields of index.html to demo.html by using a button.
Here is my code
"""

{% csrf_token %}

```
<input type="text" id="xaxis" name="xaxis"><br><br>

<input type="text" id="yaxis" name="yaxis"><br><br>

<button type="submit"> SUBMIT </button>
<button type="submit" name="saveChart" form="axisForm" value="save"> SAVE </button>
```

Comment: Post the full code of form with index.html and demo.html.

Comment: <form action="/dashapp/dashboard/" method="POST" id="axisForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="xaxis_label">Choose Schema For X Axis:</label>-->
    <input type="text" id="xaxis" name="xaxis"><br><br>

    <label for="yaxis_label">Choose Schema For Y Axis:</label>-->
    <input type="text" id="yaxis" name="yaxis"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" name="saveChart" form="axisForm" value="yaxis_schema"> SAVE </button>
</form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the form a post?

You could do something like:

```
def post(self, request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       request.session['POSTVALUES'] = request.POST.copy()
```

Then in your other view for demo.html you could call the session.

```
def get(self, request):
   post_values = request.session.get('POSTVALUES')
```

Then you could just add post_values to your context or whatever you are passing through to your demo.html view.

Comment: Kindly guide me what are POSTVALUES here? like is that value attribute or name attribute of input fields?

Comment: Sessions is basically a dictionary, so i'm just adding a new key word in being POSTVALUES but it can be any key you want and the adding the POST data.

This way I can call POSTVALUES my key in the session dictionary from another view and pass it to that views context if that makes sense?

If you need a more in-depth example let me know and ill post a full example.